# Using expandable connector to build control bus in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am learning about how to use the expandable connector in dymola. 
I am wondering how to ensure the compatibility between two control buses. My guess is that if I define an input variable called X in one control bus, then in the other one, I need to define an output variable also called X. So that when connecting these two control buses, they are coherent.
[image: bui]

Based on the above idea, I define the two expandable connectors which represent the control buses, here is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Here is the setting I used when testing my ideas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when translating the model, I got an error message like the following. It seems I got the logic wrong. My question is that how should I use the expandable connectors so that they are coherent.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is that there are two public expandable connectors (buses) at the top of the model; and both could in theory be connected from the outside.

The best option would be to not have two public buses at the top of model, e.g.:

- Remove one of the two buses
- Make one of the two buses protected
- (Or more complicated hierarchical variants.)

The [VehicleInterfaces library](https://github.com/modelica/VehicleInterfaces) does this in a good way (alternatively you can look some of the commercial libraries).

However, simplest way of making this work is to not declare anything in the buses, i.e. remove the declaration of both 'x' variables.